# O que está errado no código? Era pra ele fazer a verificação do while, mas quando digito continuar ou cancelar ele continua repetindo!

Tags: java, loop, while

```
System.out.println("Qual produto você deseja verificar a disponibilidade? ");
        System.out.println("Digite: Prato, Copo, Talheres, ou Cancelar para sair! Ou continuar "
                + "para dar seguimento a operação ");
        String produto = sc.nextLine();

    while (!produto.equalsIgnoreCase("Cancelar") || !produto.equalsIgnoreCase("Continuar")) {
        if (produto.equalsIgnoreCase("Prato")) {
            System.out.println("Nós nos dispomos de " + estoque.pratos + " pratos para locação!");
        } else if (produto.equalsIgnoreCase("Copo")) {
            System.out.println("Nós nos dispomos de " + estoque.copos + " copos para locação!");
        } else if (produto.equalsIgnoreCase("Talheres")) {
            System.out.println("Nós nos dispomos de " + estoque.talheres + " talheres para locação!");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Desculpe não entendi... :/");
        }

        System.out.println("Qual produto você deseja verificar a disponibilidade? ");
        System.out.println("Digite: Prato, Copo, Talheres, ou Cancelar para sair! ");
        System.out.println("Se você ja sabe o que vai alugar digite continuar! ");
        produto = sc.nextLine();
    }

        if (produto.equalsIgnoreCase("Cancelar")) {
            System.out.println("Tudo bem, obrigado!");
        }

        else if (produto.equalsIgnoreCase("Continuar")) {
            System.out.print("Ok, digite qual item você deseja alugar e a quantidade, ou digite cancelar: ");
            String alug = sc.nextLine();
            while (!alug.equalsIgnoreCase("Cancelar")) {
                if (alug.equalsIgnoreCase("Copos")) {
                    System.out.println("Quantos copos você deseja alugar? ");
                    estoque.aluCopos = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Para alugar " + estoque.aluCopos + " copos, fica no valor" + " de $ "
                            + estoque.PrecoCopos());
                } else if (alug.equalsIgnoreCase("Pratos")) {
                    System.out.println("Quantos pratos você deseja alugar? ");
                    estoque.aluPratos = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Para alugar " + estoque.aluPratos + " pratos, fica no valor" + " de $ "
                            + estoque.PrecoPratos());
                } else if (alug.equalsIgnoreCase("Talheres")) {
                    System.out.println("Quantos talheres você deseja alugar? ");
                    estoque.aluTalheres = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Para alugar " + estoque.aluTalheres + " talheres, fica no valor" + " de $ "
                            + estoque.PrecoTalher());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Desculpe não entendi :[");
                }
                System.out.print("Ok, digite qual item você deseja alugar e a quantidade, ou digite cancelar: ");
                alug = sc.nextLine();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A condição está errada**, deve ser:

```
while (!produto.equalsIgnoreCase("Cancelar") && !produto.equalsIgnoreCase("Continuar"))
```

Comment: m e, não acredito q era isso, aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
OBG MEO <3

Comment: Se a resposta te foi satisfatória, não deixe de [aceitá-la](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/138506), fortalece a comunidade, e todo mundo ganha.